# document.write strange behavior

Tags: javascript

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <title>Title</title>
        <script language="JavaScript">
        <!--
        function showtags()
        {
            var tag, tags;
            //document.write(document.all.length);
            tags = "The tags in the page are:"
            for(i = 0; i < document.all.length; i++)
            {
                tag = document.all(i).tagName;
                tags = tags + "<br>" + tag;
            }
            document.write(tags);
        }
        //  -->
        </script>    
    </head>
    <body onload="showtags()">
        <h1>My <b>Web</b> Page</h1>
    </body>
</html>
```

output:

The tags in the page are:
HTML
HEAD
META
TITLE
SCRIPT
BODY
H1
B

By un-commenting the first document.write() I get the following output:

8The tags in the page are:
HTML
HEAD
BODY

Some tags are missing, I don't understand where the mistake is! I thank you in advance.

Comment: `document.write` in a function is bad. It should only be used outside of a function while the dom is still being parsed. Otherwise, the existing document will be replaced with what you pass to document.write.

Comment: Where is the commented `document.write()` that you un-commented?

Comment: @Barmar When the post was initially made, the `document.write(document.all.length);` was originally commented out.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is because `document.write` being called after the document is done loading, it erases and replaces the current document. If you see here: `onload="showtags()"` that's why it's happening. `document.write` needs to be called BEFORE the DOM is done loading. For example:

```
<p> <script> document.write("hi"); </script> </p>
```

Is ok, because the DOM is still loading. But in a `onload`, or after the page is done loading in general , is not.

Comment: It is resolved. I placed the call to function at end of document as  described by Spencer. Thank you guys.

Answer (score 0):

Once the document has finished loading, any `document.write()` clears the current document and starts a new blank document so whatever you previously had in the document will be cleared out.

Since you're calling this function in an `onload` handler, the document has definitely finished loading so your `document.write()` is going to start a new document.